# Object and Object meta schema design

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-design

Am working on a project that will save many types of objects into the database. These include: articles, polls, writers .. etc. Some of those are unknown to me at design time so what i am trying to do is build a generic table schema that will enable me to save any type of item into this database.

My design

**Table Object**

```
objectID int
title varchar
body text
type int #will represent the ID of the type of object am inserting
```

Having that circumstances or requirements might need additional data, i decided that this will go to what i call "object metadata" as follows:

**Table Object_MetaData**

```
metaID int
metaKey varchar
metaIntKey int #representing an integer value of metaKey which is calculated using some algorithm to speed up queries
metaValue varchar(1000)
```

I am doing all the work in PHP and MySQL btw.

A couple of things came up to my mind when doing this design regarding the performance of the database on the long run:

1) Is saving int, boolean, small text, big text into the metaValue effecient?

2) on the long run  the metadata table is going to grow quite quickly. Is this a maintainance nightmare? how is MySQL going to to handle this?

3) IN php when fetching objects, i will have to loop each object to fetch its metadata, or load all metadata once using lazy loading or load any single metakey once its requested via __get magic method. So when fetching a list of say 50 objects, at least 50 select statements will be executed when using any of the methods i suggested. Is there a better more efficient way of doing this?

Any thoughts or comments on this design are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest re-architecting your solution.  This pattern is called "Entity-Attribute-Value" (EAV), and is commonly seen as an anti-pattern.  Instead, define the metadata attributes in columns (of the same table, or another if needed).  Use the proper data types as well.

I'd suggest giving [Bill Karwin's book *SQL AntiPatterns*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) a read.  It has some great insights that will give you a hand here specifically.  You can get a feel for some of it from [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back)...

Comment: Thanks, so this basically means that i have to clone tables and add columns to each table as needed right? doesn't this lead to duplication in the design of every table? this also requires that the "articles" table for example would have to be modified everytime a new requirement requires a new piece of information to be stored along with the article. The meta object design seems more flexible in this way that no alters are required on runtime. What do you think?

Comment: Why clone it?  Why not just add the metadata to the source table?  Yes it does mean it's modified every time.  But you're gaining consistency, searchability and type checking.  MetaObject design *is more flexible*, but at the expense of everything above and more...

Comment: okay, is there any other alternatives we can consider here? because more almost duplicate object tables will mean duplicate code(models) for every table. So what would you do?

Comment: @Rakan: You *could* use inheritance (both from the model and the db schema).  I'd suggest getting that book though.  It does a far better job of explaining the options and alternatives than I can...